# Dynamic pivot: how transform count(field) in character

Tags: sql-server

I use a dynamic pivot as this example and it work.

```
create table formazione (
persona nvarchar(20),
corsi nvarchar(20)
)

insert into formazione values ('mario', 'corso1');
insert into formazione values ('giovanni', 'corso1');
insert into formazione values ('antonio', 'corso2');
insert into formazione values ('marco', 'corso2');
insert into formazione values ('giacomo', 'corso3');
insert into formazione values ('andrea', 'corso3');

select * from formazione;


declare @col as nvarchar(max), 
@query as nvarchar(max);

set @col = stuff((
select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(corsi) from formazione FOR XML PATH(''), type)
.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

set @query = 'select persona, ' + @col + 
' from formazione
pivot ( 
count(corsi) for corsi in (' + @col + ')
) pvt'

execute (@query);
```

The result is

```
persona     |   corso1      | corso2        | corso3
------      | -----------   | ---------     | ------------
andrea      |   0           |  0            |   1
antonio     |   0           |   1           |   0
giacomo     |   0           |   0           |   1
giovanni    |   1           |   0           |   0
marco       |   0           |   1           |   0
mario       |   1           |   0           |   0
```

I am trying to obtain an result like this

```
persona     |   corso1      | corso2        | corso3
------      | -----------   | ---------     | ------------
andrea      |               |               |   x
antonio     |               |   x           |    
giacomo     |               |               |   x
giovanni    |   x           |               |    
marco       |               |   x           |    
mario       |   x           |               |
```

I want to change *count(corsi)* result: 1 to "x" , 0 to empty. There are only two result (you can not get any more results).
I think I have to use "*case when* ..." statement but I do not know how .

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
MSSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iif as below:

```
declare @col as nvarchar(max),
@selcol as nvarchar(max),  --new variable
@query as nvarchar(max);

set @col = stuff((
select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(corsi) from formazione FOR XML PATH(''), type)
.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

set @selcol = stuff((
select distinct ',' + 'iif('+ QUOTENAME(corsi) +'=0,'''',''x'') as '+QUOTENAME(corsi) from formazione FOR XML PATH(''), type)
.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

set @query = 'select persona, ' + @selcol + 
' from formazione
pivot ( 
count(corsi) for corsi in (' + @col + ')
) pvt'

select @query
execute (@query);
```

Output

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| persona  | corso1 | corso2 | corso3 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| andrea   |        |        | x      |
| antonio  |        | x      |        |
| giacomo  |        |        | x      |
| giovanni | x      |        |        |
| marco    |        | x      |        |
| mario    | x      |        |        |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to temporarily expand your data set with a Union All of a Cross Join of distinct persona and corsi.

```
declare @col as nvarchar(max), 
@query as nvarchar(max);

set @col = stuff((
select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(corsi) from formazione FOR XML PATH(''), type)
.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');



set @query = 'select persona, ' + @col + 
' from (
        Select persona,corsi,value=''X'' from formazione 
        Union All
        Select P.*,C.*
         From (Select Distinct persona from formazione) P
         Cross Join (Select Distinct corsi,Value='' '' from formazione) C
       ) A
pivot ( 
max(value) for corsi in (' + @col + ')
) pvt'

execute (@query);
```

Returns

```
persona corso1  corso2  corso3
andrea                  X
antonio         X    
giacomo                 X
giovanni        X        
marco           X    
mario   X
```